# Isn't every finite cyclic group a free group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I thought that, as a finitely generetade group, every cyclic group was free. But in homological algebra we have the result "If $F$ is a free group then $H_i(F,A)=H^i(F,A)=0$ for every $i\geq 2$ and for every left $F$-module $A$." Though we also have the following result "If G is a finite cyclic group of order $n$, then
$$H_i(G,\mathbb{Z})=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\mathbb{Z},\textrm{ if }i=0\\ \mathbb{Z}_n,\textrm{ if }i\textrm{ is odd}\\ 0,\textrm{ if $i$ is even}\end{array}\right."$$
How is that not contraditory?

Comment: Why do you think any cyclic group is free?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_n$ isn't free, because it has the relation $x^n = e$. The only free group generated by one element is $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is the defininition of "free" in your opinion.

Comment: I think I was mistaking it with free module's definition

Comment: @André Gomes A free abelian group is the same thing as a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Of course, $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is free as a $\mathbb{Z}/n$-module. Perhaps that is what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall, that any nontrivial finite group cannot be free, since the elements of a free generating set of a free group have infinite order. The infinite cyclic group is free, of course.